# SQL Cross Join and IIF(ISNULL) - Not Working as Expected

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm writing a query with a report file, an employee file and a report distribution file.  I would like a list of employee names, each with every report name and a 0 if they don't get the report and a 1 if they do get the report.

```
 select distinct ut.user_name
      , ut.emailaddress
      , r.name
      , iif(ISNULL(rd.employeeid,0)=0, 0,1) AS currentreport
 from   US_usertable ut 
 cross join DL_reports r
 left outer join DL_Reptdistrib rd 
   on ut.employeeID = rd.employeeid
```

For each user, I get a complete set of reports - so the cross join works - but either they get a 1 for all the reports or a 0 for all their reports.  I don't understand why this query isn't working.  Kindly help if you can.  Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Without looking at the data it is hard to tell.

Comment: You want a left join not a cross join.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are missing a join condition on the *report*:

```
select ut.user_name, ut.emailaddress, r.name,
       (case when rd.employeeid is null then 0 else 1 end) as currentreport
from US_usertable ut cross join
     DL_reports r left outer join
     DL_Reptdistrib rd
     on ut.employeeID = rd.employeeid and r.?? = rd.??;
```

The `??` is for the field used to identify the report.  I might guess that it is `reportID`.

Note:  I switched the syntax to standard SQL.  `IIF()` is in SQL Server for compatibility with MS Access (why Microsoft didn't put the ANSI standard `case` in MS Access is beyond me).  I also replaced `ISNULL()` with the ANSI standard `IS NULL`.

Comment: Thank you so much!!!  Worked like a charm :)  Also thank you for the updates to my code!

Comment: Gordon -- doesn't this make DL_reports a inner join to DL-Reptdistrib and basically a left join on US_usertable?

Comment: @Hogan . . . No.  The `cross join` generates all the rows the OP wants (all combinations of users and reports).  The `left join` adds in the information about what currently exists.